# Laravel 4.2 count how many rows are inserted today

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

we have want to display how many rows are inserted today in the database,unfortunately our current laravel version is 4.2?
Can anybody help us

```
  $nr=CardComment::count('created_at')->where('created_at' > today_date);
```

Comment: Just switch the where and the count.

Comment: what about today date,how to get it?does it get automatically

Comment: Try: `$nr=CardComment::where('created_at' > $today_date)->count();`

Comment: Carbon now give you today date! Like: `$today_date = Carbon\Carbon::now();`

Comment: @HirenGohel I dont have the Carbon Model

Comment: @ElizabethD. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: fixed it         blabla

Comment: Ok, it's good! Is my answer works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option here would be to use a raw `WHERE` clause:

```
$nr = CardComment::whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()')
          ->count('created_at')
```

The advantage of this approach is that "today" does not depend on an external PHP variable, but rather is handled directly by MySQL.

Comment: How can I pass this var into my view board-blade.php

Comment: @ElizabethD. I don't understand your question.